# Script like google suggest in python

Tags: python, ajax

I am writing a script that works like google suggest. Problem is that I am trying to get a suggestion for next 2 most likely words.
The example uses a txt file working_bee.txt. When writing a text "mis" I should get suggestions like "Miss Mary , Miss Taylor, ...". I only get "Miss, ...". I suspect the Ajax responseText method gives only a single word? 
Any ideas what is wrong?

`# Something that looks like Google suggest`

```
def count_words(xFile):
    frequency = {} 
    words=[]
    for l in open(xFile, "rt"):
        l = l.strip().lower()
        for r in [',', '.', "'", '"', "!", "?", ":", ";"]:
            l = l.replace(r, " ")
        words += l.split()
    for i in range(len(words)-1): 
        frequency[words[i]+" "+words[i+1]] = frequency.get(words[i]+" "+words[i+1], 0) + 1 
    return frequency

# read valid words from file 
ws = count_words("c:/mod_python/working_bee.txt").keys()

def index(req):
    req.content_type = "text/html"
    return '''
<script>
function complete(q) {
    var xhr, ws, e

    e = document.getElementById("suggestions")
    if (q.length == 0) {
        e.innerHTML = ''
        return
    }
    xhr = XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open('GET', 'suggest_from_file.py/complete?q=' + q, true)
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            ws = eval(xhr.responseText)
            e.innerHTML = ""
            for (i = 0; i < ws.length; i++)
                e.innerHTML += ws[i] + "<br>"

        }
    }
    xhr.send(null)

}
</script>
<input type="text" onkeyup="complete(this.value)">
<div id="suggestions"></div>
'''

def complete(req, q):
    req.content_type = "text"
    return [w for w in ws if w.startswith(q)]
```

txt file:

```
IV. Miss Taylor's Working Bee

"So you must. Well, then, here goes!" Mr. Dyce swung her up to his shoulder and went, two steps at a time, in through the crowd of girls, so that he arrived there first when the door was opened. There in the hall stood Miss Mary Taylor, as pretty as a pink.

"I heard there was to be a bee here this afternoon, and I've brought Phronsie; that's my welcome," he announced.

"See, I've got a bag," announced Phronsie from her perch, and holding it forth.

So the bag was admired, and the girls trooped in, going up into Miss Mary's pretty room to take off their things. And presently the big library, with the music-room adjoining, was filled with the gay young people, and the bustle and chatter began at once.

"I should think you'd be driven wild by them all wanting you at the same minute." Mr. Dyce, having that desire at this identical time, naturally felt a bit impatient, as Miss Mary went about inspecting the work, helping to pick out a stitch here and to set a new one there, admiring everyone's special bit of prettiness, and tossing a smile and a gay word in every chance moment between.

"Oh, no," said Miss Mary, with a little laugh, "they're most of them my Sunday- school scholars, you know."
```

Comment: Might I suggest writing out the steps you are trying to complete one by one and working with them individually instead of as a whole project. It allows you to figure out where you made your mistake. In the mean time I will gladly try and help you with this.

Comment: Also what server are you using to run the index & complete functions? Without this it is hard to understand what might be going wrong.

Comment: I'm using Apache 2.2. I reviewed the code step by step and I suspect the server returns only the first word in onreadystatechange function. Python functions give the right results.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I believe you are not sending the correct thing to Apache. You are sending apache a list and apache is expecting a string. I would suggest changing your return to json:

```
import json
def complete(req, q):
    req.content_type = "text"
    return json.dumps([w for w in ws if w.startswith(q)])
```

Comment: Thank you for this but I'm using Python 2.5 and trying to install simplejson but having problems. It seems like it installs ok but when I try to import I get error "No module named simplejson". Any ideas how to install?

Comment: What system are you on and how are you trying to install it?

Comment: There are many ways to install a python library. One which happens to be my favorite is [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip). Another would just be the basic setup.py script that most libraries come with. And the last would be to download the source code and unzip/untar the source folder (the one with the project name which in this case is simplejson) to the folder that you are running the script inside.

Comment: I managed to do it (the last option you described). Now I get the error in browser (FireFox) when running script... ImportError: No module named simplejson. Json works ok in python.

Comment: Well you will need to install it as you did for python into the directory where apache finds your script... But I'm not so sure that that will work with apache... You may have to figure out how to install it to the python. Question do you have 2 different versions of python installed? That may be why you are able to install simplejson but not have json work... I've hit myself for that one more than once...

Comment: I have Pythin 2.5 only. I'll try with easy install.

Comment: Easy install or pip is the best way to go.